# не работает or в if'e в js

Tags: javascript

```
 but.addEventListener("click", function(e){ 
 let r = randomColor(col.value);   
 let g = randomColor(col.value); 
 let b = randomColor(col.value);
 if (col.value="red"){
      if ((r<g) or (r<b)){
         if (g>b){
             r=g;
         }else{
             r=b;
         }
         g=g/2;
         b=b/2;
      }
 }
```

Это кусок кода, не спрашиваете что там происходит)) у меня в 6 строчке не работает Or, ошибка такая -

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

гуглил и пробовал ||, ошибка слегка меняется но все равно не работает. Я с с++ перешел только на js, еще не освоился

Comment: `if (col.value=="red"){`

Comment: Благодарю, Однако проблема все таки не в этом

Comment: if (col.value == "red"){
      if (r<g || r<b){
         r = g > b ? g : b;
         g = g/2;
         b = b/2;
      }
 }

Comment: С `||` всё должно работать

Comment: @CrazyElf Там в ife приравнивание

Comment: `Я с с++ перешел` как-бы в C++ оператор или, тоже записывается как `||`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">            
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" value="Поле ввода" id="col">
  <button id="but">я кнопка</button>
  <script>
  'use strict'
      
  function randInt(min, max){
      return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
  }
  
  function randomColor(a){
      if (a==''){
          let a = randInt(0, 255);
          let b = randInt(0, 255);  
          let c = randInt(0, 255);
          return [a, b, c];
      }
      if (a=="red"){
          let a = randInt(0, 255);
          let b = 0;  
          let c = 0;
          return [a, b, c];
      }
      if (a=="blue"){
          let a = 0;
          let b = 0;  
          let c = randInt(0, 255);
          return [a, b, c];
      }
      if (a=="green"){
          let a = 0;
          let b = randInt(0, 255);  
          let c = 0;
          return [a, b, c]
      }
      
  }
        
  function decToHex(n) {
   return n.toString(16);
  }
  

  
 but.addEventListener("click", function(e){
     console.log('col', col.value)
     let rgbArray = randomColor(col.value);
     console.log('rgbArray', rgbArray);

     document.body.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${rgbArray[0]},${rgbArray[1]},${rgbArray[2]})`;
     
 });
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Получилось, я дал ответ на ранее заданный вопрос по этой же теме. Хотелось бы еще немного пояснить, в чем там была проблема. Цветовая модель RGB - смешение трех цветов - красного, синего и зеленого. Невозможно получить оттенок одного из этих цветов, задавая случайные значения сразу для всех трех. (вернее, можно, но только если сильно повезет :) Поэтому задаем случайное значение для нужного цвета, остальные два - ставим в ноль.

Comment: Ты золото. Не можешь пояснить что значит строка `rgb(${rgbArray[0]},${rgbArray[1]},${rgbArray[2]})`; ? Я это не проходил, вообще впервые такое вижу если честно. Еще вопросик - почему в return'ах квадратные скобки?

Comment: `rgb(${rgbArray[0]},${rgbArray[1]},${rgbArray[2]})` Обратные кавычки - это существенно. В них заключается текстовая строка, в котрую ты можешь подставить переменные, выделяя их ${}

Comment: Нигде в гугле нормального обьяснения найти не могу. Почему document.body.style.backgroundColor ="#"+rgbArray[0]+rgbArray[1]+rgbArray[2] не работает, и почему return с квадратными скобочками, а не с обычными? везде где ищу их вообще нет...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-color

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray